# Deleting a row from a filtered data using Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have added a filter using app scripts to my data & I was trying to delete ONLY the filtered data, but seems like my function is ignoring the filters.
For example if I have 10 rows of data & after filtering out, there are 2 rows, my function will delete the 1st two rows of the original data & not exactly the filtered 2 rows.

If I try to use - "getDataRange().getDisplayvalues();" in the filtered sheet, it still shows complete data of the sheet. But when I copy it to another sheet, only filtered rows are copied.

I am trying to figure out a way to delete the filtered rows without moving the data to any other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The function `sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter` tells you whether or not a row is hidden by a filter. You can loop through the range to get all non-hidden rows, like so:

```
function deleteVisibleRows() {
  let sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for(let i = sh.getLastRow();i > 1;i--) {
    if(!sh.isRowHiddenByFilter(i)) {
      console.log(`Deleting row: [${i}]`);
      sh.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you specifically highlight why we are using the "reverse for loop" (i--)?

Comment: To not mess with the index during the looping. For example, if row 3 is visible and deleted, `i` set to three to `4` on the next iteration. But the row that was previously row 4 has now become row 3 due to the deletion of the previous row and would thus be skipped.

Comment: Alright!! The code is working fine...Thanks!!